# How to conditionally merge an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, filter

I have a problem, I don't know how to solve it, I will try not to give too much context and focus on the problem

A worker marks hours every day in his work, this is stored in the "dayli_data" array when the worker did not perform his hours then the "time_off" array is returned

I have two arrays that I don't know how to unify, when dayli_data brings the information I must check if the user_id is different from the time_off and if it is, I must bring the list of "...dayli_data" + what it found in "...time_off"

So let's say that the user with ID = 957706 on **10/29/2022** marked 8 hours

```
[
{
   user_id: 957706,
   tracked: 8,
   date: "2022-10-29"
},
{
   user_id: 1171637,
   tracked: 8,
  date: "2022-10-29"
}
]
```

But on **10/31/2022** he don't mark hours, so in the record "dayli_data" it won't come **(just a short example of the data)**

```
[
 {
   user_id: 1171637,
   tracked: 8,
  date: "2022-10-29"
} 
]
```

But it brings information in the time_off array

```
[{ user_id: 957706, reason: 'permission', tracked: 4, entry_date: "2022-10-31"}]
```

then I should be able to unify the arrays and return:

```
[
{
   user_id: 957706,
   tracked: 4,
   reason: 'permission',
  date_start: "2022-10-31",
  date: "2022-10-31"
},
{
   user_id: 1171637,
   tracked: 7,
   date: "2022-10-31"
}
]
```

How can I conditionally merge arrays?

I tried this:

```js
let data_daily = [{
    "id": 6583194952,
    "date": "2022-10-31",
    "user_id": 1171637,
    "project_id": 2082652,
    "task_id": 111873721,
    "keyboard": 3891,
    "mouse": 8714,
    "overall": 11875,
    "tracked": 29494,
    "input_tracked": 29494,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 17700,
    "created_at": "2022-10-31T14:14:05.300434Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-10-31T11:02:04.105898Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 6583205067,
    "date": "2022-10-31",
    "user_id": 1762437,
    "project_id": 2082652,
    "task_id": 111407896,
    "keyboard": 3843,
    "mouse": 13066,
    "overall": 15760,
    "tracked": 29275,
    "input_tracked": 29275,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 29275,
    "created_at": "2022-10-31T14:15:54.284572Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-10-31T11:01:52.894533Z"
  }
]

let time_off = [{
    "user_id": 957963,
    "date_start": "2022-10-31",
    "date_end": "2022-11-05",
    "rol": "DEV",
    "reason": "Permiso",
    "created_at": "2022-10-31T15:46:42+00:00",
    "kpi": "permission",
    "activity": 60,
    "tracked": 4,
    "user": {
      "user_id": 957963,
      "name": "Isaac xxx",
      "email": "isaac.correo@c.com",
      "status": "active",
      "created_at": "2022-10-31T06:36:42.898255Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-10-31T13:59:08.095330Z",
      "daily_hours": 8,
      "username": "ISAAC XXX",
      "time_work": "FULLTIME",
      "job_position": "Junior"
    }
  },
  {
    "user_id": 957706,
    "date_start": "2022-10-31",
    "date_end": "2022-10-31",
    "rol": "DEV",
    "reason": "permission",
    "created_at": "2022-10-31T06:18:25+00:00",
    "kpi": "permission",
    "activity": 60,
    "tracked": 4,
    "user": {
      "user_id": 957706,
      "name": "Cesar xxxx",
      "email": "cesarz@c.com",
      "status": "active",
      "created_at": "2022-10-31T19:41:27.759263Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-10-31T15:20:46.296994Z",
      "daily_hours": 8,
      "username": "CESAR XXXX",
      "time_work": "FULLTIME",
      "job_position": "Junior "
    }
  }
]

const result = data_daily.map(element => {
  return time_off.length > 0 ? { ...time_off
  } : { ...element
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

But it only returns the elements of the time_off. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try like `{...time_off, ...element}` or `{...element, ...time_off}` in your return statement.

Comment: Could you [edit] your code to be a self-contained [mre] that isn't pseudocode? `10/31/2002` is not a valid date.  The more you can make your code testable in an IDE, the more likely you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: Even after your edit if I run your code it gives `"date_start": 0.00015953543281962924`, because that's `10` divided by `31` divided by `2002`. I know this isn't the point of your question, but it would be nice if these distractions were not present.

Comment: Hello @slbox, thanks for answering me, I tried your proposal and what it does to wrap time_off in all the elements that "data_daily" returns, that is, it does not unify the two arrays, but rather assigns it to the elements that it brings within each one of the elements of "data_daily"

Comment: Hello @jcalz Thanks for your suggestion, Is the date format wrong? I used it as an example really

Comment: Your date format is fine now, I guess, I'm just saying that it's a distraction to use `1/2/3`.  Maybe you should work on providing an example that gives the minimum amount of data needed to distinguish blindly merging both arrays from merging "correctly". If each input array contains just one element you will get answers that just concat them.  I have an idea of what you're trying to do but your example is too minimal to demonstrate it

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean, I'm going to edit the answer with the json of my actual data to make the example more realistic. Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will edit the snippet

Comment: Well, if your "actual data" is very long, I'd hope you'd trim it down.  Perhaps [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVbDxN) would perform the merging operation how you'd like, but I'd need more data (but not a huge amount) to be sure.

Comment: Modify the snippet, I keep keeping an example with the short sample data so as not to confuse too much when I try to explain my problem, I think this is fine, or should I change it?

Comment:  That's not what I was asking; adding more data to each entry just makes things complicated, and you still made your `user_id`s completely disjoint, so no merging would take place.  Wait, are they *always* going to be disjoint? Then why not just concatenate the arrays?  If a `user_id` will never appear in both arrays, then just write `const result = [...data_daily, ...time_off]` and be done with it.  Where's the "conditional" thing you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding maybe you're looking for something like this:

```js
let data_daily = [{
  "user_id": 2,
  "tracked": 7,
  "date": "2022-10-31"
}]

let time_off = [{
  "user_id": 1,
  "reason": 'permission',
  "tracked": 4,
  "date_start": "2022-10-31"
}]


const result = time_off.reduce((resultArray, currTimeOff) => [...resultArray, currTimeOff], data_daily);

console.log(result)
```

### Extra:

This is how JS [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) works.

Comment: Yes, that's all I need, thank you very much, you saved me my life, I'm still learning Javascript and I still have a lot to understand about how to handle data with arrays, how to concatenate, etc. I will continue studying, but in this case, why does reduce act in this way?

Comment: `reduce` composes multiple things into one, in your case you need to merge two arrays into one. so first I started from the original `data_daily` array and just pushed new elements from `time_off` to that array by spread operator like this: [...oldArrayValues, newValue].

Answer (score 1):

Just add in the same object that is returned the other object (which is `element`) with the three dots `...`. The three dots allows us to instantly mapping an object's values into another. So, to fix it try the following `.js` code:

```
let data_daily = [{
  "user_id": 2,
  "tracked": 7,
   "date": 10/31/2022
}]

let time_off = [{ "user_id": 1, "reason": 'permission', "tracked": 4, "date_start": 10/31/2022}]

const result = data_daily.map(element => {
  return time_off.length > 0 ? {...time_off, ...element } : { ...element }
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hello @Franco, thanks for answering me, I tried your suggestion and what it does is assign the result of "time_off" within each of the elements of "data_daily"